# ¿Cómo enviar el resultado a una varible con mysqli_result?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli

Sé que el problema es el `mysqli_result`, pero antes utilizaba `mysql_result` y con ese no me aparecían problemas.

Éste es mi código:

```
<?php

//AQUI VIENE LA CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS

$sql="select sum(tiempo) from Row where status ="passed"and examen= 'matematicas'";
$rs=mysqli_connect($conn, $sql);
if(!$rs){
exit("error en el query");
}
while(mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){
$CoreD= mysqli_result($rs,"tiempo");
}
```

Comment: Independientemente de que `mysqli_result` esté fallando, el código de arriba contiene errores que harán que nada funcione: variables usadas sin ser definidas (aunque esto puede ser porque sólo has compartido parte del código), una cadena de texto mal formada, funciones con parámetros incorrectos...

Answer (score 2):

> Nota: como indico en el comentario de arriba, el código que compartes contiene errores (cadenas mal formadas, parámetros incorrectos) que harán que no funcione bien. Mi respuesta no se va a centrar en esos errores, sino exclusivamente en la parte relacionada a `mysqli_result`.

El problema que te estás encontrando es que `mysql_result` y `mysqli_result` son dos cosas completamente diferentes, y no existe correspondencia entre las dos:

- [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php):

  - Es un método.
  - Devuelve una cadena de texto con el contenido de una celda en un *resultset*.
- [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php):

  - Es una clase.
  - Representa el *resulset* devuelto tras una consulta.

En la documentación de `mysqli_result` puedes ver una [nota escrita por tuxedobob](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php#109782) en la que explica cómo podría simularse el antiguo comportamiento de `mysql_result` usando métodos MySQLi (hay que cambiarle el nombre a la función o crearía un conflicto con la clase, entonces usarías esa función en lugar de `mysqli_result`):

```
<?php 
function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) { 
    $res->data_seek($row); 
    $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
    return $datarow[$field]; 
} 
?>
```